# Recursive Removal in Binary Search tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am working on a binary search tree and I have gotten a little stuck in my recursive remove method. Everything seems to work except when I try to remove from the very top root. When I want to remove from the root I am to replace it with the smallest value to the right of the root. It works for every other sub-root but when I try to remove the first root it won't replace the value. But it will remove the value is suppose to be used to replace it. I would really appreciate some advice.

```
def remove_element(self, t):
    if self.__root == None:
       raise ValueError
    else:
       self.__remove_element(t, self.__root)
    return self.__root
```

Comment: I infer that this code is part of a class. Can we see the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `remove_element` never assigns to `self.__root` (and nothing assigns to any “value” attribute), so of course the root never changes.